# Question: Compare the cardinality between the sets $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was comparing the sets $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for a fun practice because I didn't know at first that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ was uncountable. But how can I compare two uncountable sets and see which has the larger cardinality?

Comment: $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable. It's a nice exercise to prove.

Comment: Maybe the OP meant $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I meant N^N, can someone edit my post yet again so I can see how to write it as well?

Comment: Do you know the Cantor-Bernstein theorem? (If $|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$ then $|A|=|B|$)

Comment: Comparing two uncountable sets is even more difficult than you might have expected it to be, as witnessed by the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: The Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, a.k.a. the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, a.k.a. the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem.... There are 2 proofs, one long & complicated, the other short & sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to approach this might be to show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality, and then find a way to compare the cardinality of $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (which seems to be easier).

The intuition is that the base-2 representation of any real nomber can be considered as an element of $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{\mathbb{N}}$.
(But you'll see that in practice, althought we intuitively understand why $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality, it's not that simple to build a bijection between the 2 and requires a good amount of work.)

Just a suggestion thought.

Comment: Rather than making a bijection between $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ and $\Bbb R$, it's easier to construct one injection in either direction. Of course, that they therefore have equal cardinality isn't entirely obvious without a certain theorem.

Comment: Ah yes, since the OP doesn't ask for an explicit bijection between the 2 sets, one can use the Bernstein theorem indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explicit bijection $f$ from $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ to the half-open interval $[0,1)$ of the real line. I'll write elements of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ as infinite sequences of natural numbers, and I'll adopt the convention that $0\in\mathbb N$. Define $f(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ to be the real number with binary expansion
$$
.\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{a_0\text{ ones}}0 \underbrace{11\cdots1}_{a_1\text{ ones}}0 
\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{a_2\text{ ones}}0\cdots.
$$
Notice that, although some numbers have two binary expansions, one ending with all zeros and one ending with all ones, only the former will be produced by $f$, so $f$ is one-to-one. Its image clearly consists of all reals in the unit interval, including the endpoint $0=f(0,0,0,\dots)$ but excluding the endpoint $1$.

To get an explicit bijection from $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ to all of $\mathbb R$ rather than just the unit interval, combine $f$ with your favorite bijection $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$, and send $(b_0b_1,b_2,\dots)$ to $g(b_0)+f(b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots)$.

Comment: And then one can get a bijection from [0,1) to (0,1) (various methods exist), then play around with tan to get a bijection to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @HarmonicSun Note that, in the last paragraph of my answer, I showed how to get a bijection to $\mathbb R$ without going via $(0,1)$ (and without tan).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is indeed not countable, as it includes a representation of $2^\mathbb{N}$,
the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, and power sets have a larger cardinality than the base set.

The continuum hypothesis is that there is no cardinality between the one of $\mathbb{N}$ and the one of $\mathbb{R}$, so 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{card}{card}
\card(\mathbb{N}) = \aleph_0
< \card(2^\mathbb{N}) 
= \card(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})
= \card(\mathbb{R})
= \mathfrak{c}
$$
if one accepts the CH.

Comment: No need to assume CH.

Comment: You have made the same mistake as twnly: assuming without justification that $|2^\mathbb N| = |\mathbb N ^ \mathbb N|$.

Comment: Hope this is a better wording.

Answer (score 0):

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, if you have a bijection $f:A \rightarrow B$ then we say that they have the same cardinality. If $f$ is an injection then this tells us that $|A| \leq |B|$ where, for any $X$, $|X|$ represents the cardinality of $X$.

So, to answer your question, to show that say, $|A| < |B|$, we need to show that there is an injection $f \rightarrow B$ this is often not too difficult but we also need to show that there is no injection $g: B \rightarrow A$. This is usually a bit harder.

When we show that the reals are bigger than the natural numbers we use the diagonal argument to show that no such injection exists although I realise this example doesn't quite work as you asked about uncountable sets but the same principle applies: it's hard to show that an injection does not exist. It's a bit like in topology when, to show that two spaces are not equivalent, we have to show that no homeomorphism exists (that is why topological invariants are so useful in topology, they help with this.